# Enhancing User Experience with Apps on Desktop

Tags: notifications, minimize

For about a week I've been searching alternatives to MacOS, trying several Linux distros and various combinations of VM's for both OS's -- installing apps from repositories and command-line -- interfacing a file-system change from APFS to EXT4 & ZFS. So far, I like ElementaryOS the best, as everything seems to work & it's pretty fast. However, problems exist managing multiple open apps.

1. For some apps, like a text editor, how to put multiple tabs in one window?
2. Sometimes there's no global menu (file, edit, view, windows, etc) and no app-ID. Is this browser firefox, chrome, brave?
3. Apps are similar in appearance (black/white/grey) and hard to tell apart. When I open one, it's hidden behind other open apps.
4. How to minimize an app; how to prevent it from suddenly enlarging to fill whole screen.
5. Create a Mac-like dock, with apps arranged vertically along the left margin -- never overwritten by an open app.
6. Prevent notification from grabbing cursor control while I'm typing.

After a struggle akin to Ahab and the whale, I'm considering sinking a few grand into a new Mac and go back to what worked all along -- despite preferring Linux independence.

Still, this is a great distro, and I haven't given up yet !!
Any help much appreciated, and thanks to all for all the great work.

Comment: Welcome! There are certainly a lot of initial similarities between eOS and MacOS, but the two are drastically different when it comes to application consistency. This is primarily due to the “culture” of developers who follow Apple or those who follow Linux. Mac apps work only on Mac and follow a set number of expectations. Linux apps run on many different versions of Linux with many different interfaces and many individualized sets of preferences. I have used eOS, Ubuntu, and MacOS daily for years. Nothing is as consistent as MacOS.